# Is numpy array automatically distributed on cluster?

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a distributed spark data frame df. if using

```
data_array =  np.array(df.select("height", "weight", "gender").collect())
```

is this data_array automatically distributed? Will there be any memory issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Using `collect` will move all data onto your driver node, and `np.array` will just create a local Numpy array on the single driver node machine. You will run out of memory if the array is too big.

To use distributed matrix in `pyspark`, try checking the `Distributed matrix` category (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#distributed-matrix). However, some matrix operations in there are very slow, so you may want to consider using a mix of `UDF` and optimised matrix operations from `scipy` on `pyspark DataFrame` directly.

Comment: I found all 3 Apache Systemml deep learning methods are using Numpy Array as input. https://systemml.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/deep-learning   If the input is not distributed, how is this the distributed deep learning?

Comment: SystemML allows both Spark dataframe and Python objects (e.g. Numpy array) for inputs. For Python objects, they will not be parallelised at source and presumably only parallelised when you pass them into the functions.